# why NullPointer Exception

Tags: android

I encountered this problem in the development process, this class has androidManifest been registered, but still have this problem, use in androidManifest package name after my confirmation are correct

```
Error log:Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cs.flyox/com.cs.flyox.activity.SelectFormWorkActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
'2013-04-02 19:28:33    
Error log:android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
'2013-04-02 19:28:33    
Error log:android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
'2013-04-02 19:28:33    
Error log:android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
'2013-04-02 19:28:33    
Error log:android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
'2013-04-02 19:28:33    
Error log:android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
'2013-04-02 19:28:33    
Error log:android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
'2013-04-02 19:28:33    
Error log:android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
'2013-04-02 19:28:33    
Error log:java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
'2013-04-02 19:28:33    
Error log:java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
'2013-04-02 19:28:33    
Error log:com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
'2013-04-02 19:28:33    
Error log:com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
'2013-04-02 19:28:33    
Error log:dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: Post more logs and some of your activity's code.

Comment: Why? Because Null. Find out what's null, and don't access it.

Comment: if you don't mind post the code??

Comment: Post your code then only you get better answer.

Comment: Sorry, due to confidentiality, I can not post my code

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreate() method of your activity, you are making a call that returns a null pointer.  For example, in my activity, I did a create method like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, R.layout.landing);
    String pig = savedCueCardActivity.getAction();
}
```

and it created a debug output like this:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.raac.student/com.raac.student.LandingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

because this line:

```
String pig = savedCueCardActivity.getAction();
```

returns a null.  You have something similar in your onCreate, and you should be able to find it with setting a break point in there, or perhaps even more carefully looking at your full debugger output.